# How to use batch file to change permissions of registry to remove network from navigation pane

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, windows-explorer

I'd like to change the following registry path's permissions to allow Administrators full control. The registry path is:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}\ShellFolder
```

I'd also like to change the value of the DWORD named Attributes inside this registry path to b0940064. What code would I use for this? Can I use cacls for this?

Comment: Try it, if it doesn't work, try something else. Once you've researched and tested your code, if it fails to work as written, post the code with a full explanation of what happened which differed from your intent. This isn't a give me the code type of site, please take the [tour] and read [ask], before [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53904817/edit) accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[SetACL](https://helgeklein.com/setacl/)**, but after need use it too: DesktopRefresh.exe

Obs: This is super user **[question](https://superuser.com/questions/712392/change-registry-permissions-via-command-line-batch-file)**

Take a little look here, for **[key value](https://www.askvg.com/windows-10-tip-remove-onedrive-quick-access-homegroup-and-network-icons-from-navigation-pane-of-this-pc/)**

```bat
SetACL.exe -on "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}" -ot reg -actn setowner -ownr n:Administrators
SetACL.exe -on "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}" -ot reg -actn ace -ace "n:Administrators;p:full"
reg import "%path_to_file%\rey_with_value_to_change.reg"
```

Comment: Thank you, that made it a lot simpler :)

Comment: I'm happy for this work to you! Merry Christmas! And thank you too!

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too!

Comment: Modifying the registry via HKCR is unreliable. It's a merged view, and the key you actually get depends on what already exists. Unfortunately Microsoft's own docs often do this with the occasional fine print discussion that it's just meant for demonstration and production code should modify the real key in "[HKCU | HKLM]\Software\Classes". At this stage so many thousands of people haven't bothered to read thoroughly, or just copied other people's code, so the web is an echo chamber of bad code.

Comment: I'm running this in virtual machine so if anything messes up, it won't be anything permanent.